# Parse PHP Rest API update query not working

Tags: php, parse-platform

I want to get data and also update some rows's data.
this code retrive all data from table

```
function updateStatus(){
        $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/xxxxxxx';
        $appId = 'xxxxxxxxx';
        $restKey = 'xxxxxxxxx';
        $headers = array(
        "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey
        );
        $queryParse = '{"date":"21-04-2016"}';
        $rest = curl_init($url.$queryParse);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($rest);
        curl_close($rest);
        return $response;
    }
```

and query Parse also like

```
$queryParse = urlencode('where={"date":"21-04-2016","time":07:00 to 10:00}');
```

But both are not working.

Comment: You have to be more specific than "not working". What happens? What did you think should happen? (You can [edit] your question.)

Comment: updated the question. 
this code retrive all data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries), you should pass the `where`constraint:

```
...
$queryParse = 'where='.urlencode('{"date":"21-04-2016"}');
$rest = curl_init($url."?".$queryParse);
...
```

Comment: i replace this Query and params formate. but still retrive all data from parse class.

Comment: @Rajpoot so what's the problem? you don't get data or you get too much data? It's not explained in the question. Try to change the date format to ' 2016-04-21'

Comment: I want selected data. but this query send me all data in this class. and the format doesn't matter(because this is string). can you please tell me the correct format of query or other change in the code. help me